# Webservice returns correct data but is parsed as undefined

Tags: javascript, c#, web-services

I have this code which I use to fill a dropdown box on my website. It pulls some departments from a database and then is supposed to put the ID of the department as the options value and then the departments name as the options "name" (the name it shows)

```
/**
 * This function is Run when creating the dropdown to choose a department
 * when creating a new activity.
 */
function CreateNewActivityDepartmentDropdown() {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/GetDepartmentsForDropdown", function (data) {
        var object = $.parseJSON(data);
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("new-activity-modal-department-dropdown");
        for (var department in object) {
            if (object.hasOwnProperty(department)) {
                var array = department.split(',');
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.id = array[0];
                option.innerHTML = array[1];
                dropdown.add(option);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The Object does have the right data in it. I checked it with Google Chromes debugger. The data consist of `id,department` strings and in my for loop I try and split the string I get but first of all the value for each option seems to just be an incremental value (0-n) instead of the id's I have (1-12) and the options text is "undefined".

And sure enough when I debug I find that it seems the ID and Text is just not there. What am I missing here? Still fairly new at JavaScript development :)

**EDIT**

Added the output from `console.log(data, object)`

```
["1,Commercial","2,Economy","3,Technical Dept.","4,IT","5,Flight Op","6,Legal","7,Ground Op","8,BDO","9,Administration","10,Training","11,Passenger Service","12,Cabin"] Array[12]
```

**EDIT 2**

The object of data is received from a webservice. The Webservice is written in C# and the code I use to obtain it is below:

```
public static List<String> GetDepartmentDropdownList()
{
    List<String> departments = new List<String>();
    using (SqlConnection conn = GetSqlConnection())
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Department WHERE is_used != 0";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Int32 id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    String department = id + "," + reader.GetString(1);
                    departments.Add(department);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    return departments;
}
```

and here is what the website calls:

```
public String GetDepartmentsForDropdown()
{
    List<String> departments = Facade.GetDepartmentDropdownList();

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(departments);
}
```

Comment: `console.log(data, object)`, show us what data you're supposedly working with.

Comment: @deceze Here you go, added to the main post. :)

Comment: @SimonH — No. The property name is inserted into the `department` variable on the previous line.

Comment: Why are you concatenating with a comma in the first place instead of using a decent array/object structure?!

Comment: @deceze No reason to be upset. I come here for help not to be told how much wrong I am and not receiving help. Sorry if that seems aggressive.

Comment: I'm not particularly upset, I'm just pointing our obvious deficiencies in your code; presumably that's what you're here for.

Comment: @deceze Yes, but your use of symbols would indicate otherwise :P The internet you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested here is the solution I ended up with:

```
/**
 * This function is Run when creating the dropdown to choose a department
 * when creating a new activity.
 */
function CreateNewActivityDepartmentDropdown() {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/GetDepartmentsForDropdown", function (data) {
        var object = $.parseJSON(data);
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("new-activity-modal-department-dropdown");
        for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
            var array = object[i].split(',');
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = array[0];
            option.innerHTML = array[1];
            dropdown.add(option);
        }
    });
}
```

No C# code edits needed. I don't know about the solution that Quentin gave me but it appears that without doing this step:

```
var object = $.parseJSON(data);
```

There was no way I could make it work. I'd be happy to give the answer points to however can explain this.

Answer (score 1):

`getJSON` parses the HTTP response body as JSON before populating `data` with it.

`var object = $.parseJSON(data);` will convert the array into a string and then try to parse that as JSON (which will fail because it isn't JSON). Don't do that.

Comment: Hm. The object itself is serialized as Json through the webservice using Newton Softs library for the job. Before I receive it that is.

Comment: @Vipar — Are you saying that the HTTP response consists of a JSON text representation of a JSON string which itself contains the JSON text representation of a JSON array?

Comment: I probably should elaborate a bit. I've added some more code to the question.

Comment: @Vipar — I can't see anything indicating that the server is double encoding the data … so my answer stands. Stop double decoding it.

Comment: I tried to just use the "data" object instead of using parseJSON as you (seem?) to suggest but now I still have "undefined" and I have about 3 times as many "undefined" options to choose from compared to before.